# How can I WPF bind dynamically created checkboxes to dynamically created series in LiveCharts?

Tags: wpf, checkbox, dynamic, livecharts

I have a liveChart and am creating checkboxes for each item in a list.  This list also has data for each series in liveCharts.  How do I bind my dynamically created checkboxes with each individual LiveCharts.LineSeries from my data?

I've created the checkboxes:

```
<!-- Creating checkboxes by binding to list -->
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementItemList}" 
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Width="600">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ElementName}" />
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=ElementIsSelected}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>

<!-- Display the chart -->
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="TestGrid"></Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I assume that you want to have a `CheckBox` representing each `LineSeries` in your `SeriesCollection`.

So I would have two `public` properties, one for the `SeriesCollection` and the other for the list of `CheckBox` controls.

```
public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
public List<CheckBox> CheckBoxCollection { get; set; }
```

Then following is a function that mimics dynamically creating your `LineSeries` and `CheckBox` controls since you didn't provide that code. It is important to have some sort of a connection between the `CheckBox` controls and your line series, and in this case I decided to set `LineSeries.Title` and `CheckBox.Name` the same.

Also note that in order to have the `CheckBox` do something upon checking/unchecking, you'd need to register two events for each.

```
public void DynamicallyCreateStuff()
{
    SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection();
    CheckBoxCollection = new List<CheckBox>();

    var count = 3;
    var val1 = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3 };
    var val2 = new List<double>() { 9, 5, 3 };
    var val3 = new List<double>() { 1, 4, 9 };

    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        var name = string.Format("LineSeries{0}", i);

        var checkBox = new CheckBox
        {
            Name = name,
            Content = name,
            Margin = new Thickness() { Left = 8, Top = 8, Right = 8, Bottom = 8 },
            IsChecked = true
        };
        checkBox.Checked += DynamicCheckBoxChecked;
        checkBox.Unchecked += DynamicCheckBoxUnchecked;
        CheckBoxCollection.Add(checkBox);

        var lineSeries = new LineSeries
        {
            Title = name
        };
        if (i == 1)
        {
            lineSeries.Values = new ChartValues<double>(val1);
        }
        else if (i == 2)
        {
            lineSeries.Values = new ChartValues<double>(val2);
        }
        else if (i == 3)
        {
            lineSeries.Values = new ChartValues<double>(val3);
        }

        SeriesCollection.Add(lineSeries);
    }
}
```

In my case, I decided to have the corresponding series become visible/hidden upon clicking the `CheckBox`, so my check/uncheck methods look like this:

```
private void DynamicCheckBoxChecked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowHideSeries(sender, Visibility.Visible);
}

private void DynamicCheckBoxUnchecked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowHideSeries(sender, Visibility.Collapsed);
}

private void ShowHideSeries(object sender, Visibility visibility)
{
    var checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
    var found = SeriesCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Title == checkBox.Name);
    if (found != null)
    {
        var series = (LineSeries)found;
        series.Visibility = visibility;
    }
}
```

I didn't use a `ViewModel` in order to save time and for the sake of simplicity, so my `MainWindow` constructor looks like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DynamicallyCreateStuff();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

And `XAML` is pretty bare bones here:

```
<Window x:Class="SOLineCharts.MainWindow"
        ....
        xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding CheckBoxCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
        <lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### **Result:**

Upon loading:

[image]

Unchecking one check box:

[image]